# Deep frying a half turkey

Tags: deep-frying, turkey, thanksgiving

I’ve  successfully deep fried my Thanksgiving turkey for the last several years using a 30 qt pot and a poultry rack.

This year, due to COVID, it’ll just be my household so we’ll need a lot less turkey. I’m considering Deep frying a half bird. But, I’m concerned with how I’ll lower it into the frying pot and I’m worried that tying the half bird to the rack will leave the rack unbalanced and potentially dangerous for lowering in and removing.

Are my concerns valid or will using the standard poultry rack work fine? Is there some other method I should consider like a stainless steel fry basket?

Comment: Do you already have the bird?  Maybe go for a smaller turkey...8-10#?

Comment: The problem is my butcher only has 16 lb birds. So either a full 16 lb bird or a half of one.

Comment: Cook the whole thing and have lots of leftovers @Tdayturkey! Curry, soup, the possibilities are endless! Practically though, you need to explain your rig better, does the turkey hang from the leg or somewhere else? How many hooks does it have?

Comment: It's hard to tell without understanding your set-up. If you have a rack that depends on pinning the bird at either end, then this may not work with a half turkey. Using a basket might be safer, but if you have a rack to hold the basket and raise and lower it, there's a risk the weight of the bird will bend it or cause it to stick - a half turkey is a lot heavier than most things you'll deep fry, and forcing it in may bend the basket. So it might depend on the basket. You should certainly try and experiment a bit before involving hot oil.